# how do I change style of the Firefox findBar suggestions list

Tags: firefox, css

Recently I've built FF with GTK3, soon this will be the default. Although I fixed all of the GTK3 inconsistencies (borderless white elements which look ugly) I just cannot find the code for a findBar sussgetions drop-down list.

Comment: IMHO you should ask this at SO.

Comment: most of similar questions are found here. at SU.